# Customize OAuth CallBackPath Controller in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth

I want to use OAuth in my .net core web App.

On my Startup file, I've added services.AddAuthentication( .... ).AddCookies(...).AddOAuth(...);

It works properly. Now I want to customize the way my callback controller works. How can I do that?

```
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/web/callback");
```

because the API I'm working with does not implement OAuth2/OpenIdConnect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I have to fix my problem. I modified the
options.Events.OnTicketReceived in order to get the required claims.

```
 .AddOAuth("customer", options =>
            {

                options.ClientId = Configuration["clientid"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/bi/callback");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(Configuration["AuthorizationEndpoint"]).ToString();
                options.TokenEndpoint = new Uri(Configuration["TokenEndpoint"]).ToString();
                options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
                {
                  OnTicketReceived = context =>
                  {
                     // I have fixed my claim here 
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
                  }
```